# View gets Json displayed on the page. not the data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action which returns a JsonResult. The only thing gets displayed on the view is my json which is like

```
ProcessOrder{"IsValid":true,"url":"/Home/ProcessOrder"}
```

While debugging the code, I noticed that it gets displayed because of this below line.

```
 var ProcessOrderData = new { IsValid = true, url = Url.Action("ProcessOrder") };
                return new JsonResult() { Data = ProcessOrderData };
```

Can any body please tell me why it gets only json to be displayed on the view?
is something null here that is causing this to get this displayed or any other stuff?

Code:

```
 private ActionResult SubmitAccount(UserAccountModels UserAccountModels)
    {
        SessionInfo userSession = SiteSetting.Visitor;

        if (userSession != null)
        {
            if (userSession.products.Where(rec => rec.IsAddedToCart).Count() > 0)
            {
                SiteSetting.Visitor.User.FirstName = UserAccountModels.FirstName;
                SiteSetting.Visitor.User.LastName = UserAccountModels.LastName;
                SiteSetting.Visitor.User.Phone = UserAccountModels.Phone;
                SiteSetting.Visitor.User.Email = UserAccountModels.Email;
  var ProcessOrderData = new { IsValid = true, url = Url.Action("ProcessOrder") };
                return new JsonResult() { Data = ProcessOrderData };

            }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only display **Json** because you are returing `JsonResult` not a `View`

Comment: so should i return something like
return RedirectToAction("ProcessOrder");

Comment: yes return a view or action and instead of JsonResult return a model or model object in viewbag whatever is suitable in your scenario